# Pandas unable to allocate GiB for an array with shape X and data type Y

Tags: python, pandas, memory-management, out-of-memory, dask

I am manipulating time series data in a dataframe (df1) that has a bunch of input columns, 300 period columns, and 839826 rows.

If I try to only manipulate the 839826 x 300 section of this dataframe by multiplying it by a similarly shaped section of a different dataframe (df2):

```
df1.iloc[:, 0:301] = df1.iloc[:, 0:301] * df2.iloc[:, 0:301]
```

I get this error:

> Unable to allocate 1.88 GiB for an array with shape (301, 839826) and data type float64

I found the answer to a similar question, but the solution was for Linux and I am working on Windows. I have read online I should use Dask, but I am not sure about how to implement that in here, or whether it's even the right solution to go for.

Comment: Are you interested in element-wise multiplication of df1 and df2? What happens if you run: `df1 = df1 * df2`?

Comment: It won't work because they have other input columns beyond [0:301] that are not meant to be multiplicated. Some of them are not even numerical. Would creating two new dataframes `df1_new = df1.iloc[:, 0:301]` and `df2_new = df2.iloc[:, 0:301]` and then setting `df1.iloc[:, 0:301] = df1_new * df2_new` be faster / bypass the error? I am not sure how these calculations work in the background.

Comment: Hmm, the `_new` approach would work in principle, but it seems that memory is a constraint for you, so it would be great to have a solution that doesn't create copies of the data.

Comment: I should mention that I am copying this 839826 x 300 table multiple times, as the output I need is 5-10 different versions of this table (with different transformations applied to each). I think the fact that I'm doing `df1.copy()` a bunch of time is what's causing the issue, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Yes, `.copy()` will eat up your memory if you are doing it with large objects. One way to avoid it is to write things to disk (e.g. `.to_parquet()` or `.to_csv()`). Another way is through more efficient code...

Comment: So if I have this large dataframe df and I need to return `df1 = func1(df)` `df2 = func2(df)` and so on, what would be more efficient code to do that?

Comment: That's a good question. I don't know a single solution that works for all cases... but splitting the workflow into smaller bits might help, e.g. not operating on all columns at the same time, or doing operations on groups of rows.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
df1.iloc[:, 0:301] = df1.iloc[:, 0:301] * df2.iloc[:, 0:301]
```

first allocates a temporary array/dataframe from the result of the multiplication, before assigning it into the output. You can prevent this by doing only in-place operations:

```
df1.iloc[:, 0:301] = df1.iloc[:, 0:301] 
df1.iloc[:, 0:301] *= df2.iloc[:, 0:301]
```

This might get you over your immediate hurdle - but indeed do investigate Dask in case you are facing this kind of situation a lot.